# Heroku rejecting push of a Meteor app

Tags: node.js, meteor, heroku

I keep getting this error when I try to push my app to Heroku:

```
git push heroku master

Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 3.18 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: -----> Meteor version: Meteor 1.4.0.1
remote: -----> Checking if this meteor version supports --server-only
remote: cp: cannot stat ‘/app/tmp/cache/1.3.4.1/.meteor/packages/meteortool/.1.3.4_1.tskw1g++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node\n/app/tmp/cache/1.3.4.1/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.1lf30np++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node’: No such file or directory
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to [name-of-app].
```

What could the problem be? Just a few hours ago I managed to push with no errors.

Comment: What buildpack are you using ?

Comment: @distalx I'm using Meteor Buildpack Horse

Comment: have you updated your meteor version recently ?

Comment: It auto-updated to 1.4.0.1 yesterday while I was pushing to Heroku @distalx . But I'm still running 1.3.4.1 on locally. Could that be the problem?

Comment: meteor 1.4 uses node 4.4.7. could be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually a meteor version mismatch. I had to upgrade to meteor 1.4 which presented an issue of its own. If you have problems updating to 1.4, you could check out [this thread](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7469#issuecomment-236977411)

Answer (score 4):

Running this worked for me:

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_CLEAR_CACHE=1
```

It forced heroku to download meteor again and overwrite the version 1.4 that was updated automatically.  If you are using the horse buildback check how the issue evolves: https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse/issues/132

Comment: this solved the problem for me. some history:
- i deploy successfully, logs show meteor 1.2.1
- next day i try to deploy again - fails, log show meteor 1.4.1

running the above command helped
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the cache from the previous built, For that you have to install **Heroku Repo plugin**

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
```

and clear your app cache by running repo:purge_cache.
if you have multiple apps don't forget to specify your **appname**

```
heroku repo:purge_cache
```

and then you could push your code

```
git push heroku master
```